# Ejecutar método del componente hijo desde el componente padre. Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular6

Un saludo a todos

Actualmente tengo 3 componentes que se están comunicando entre sí. Se que con los decoradores `@input` puedo pasar información del padre al hijo. Pero no se como puedo ejecutar un método del hijo desde el padre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer que cuando se ejecute el método `guardarSolicitud()` del componente `Solicitud`, también se ejecute el método `servicioAPIGuardar()` del componente `Codeudor`.

Esto es debido a que al guardar la solicitud se obtiene un id que se usa para relacionar a los `deudores` con la `solicitud` en la BD.

Para que pase algo como

```
guardarSolicitud() {

    let solicitudData: any = {
      ...this.solicitudForm.value,
    };

    this.solicitudesService.createSolicitud(solicitudData)
      .pipe(finalize(() => {
        this.wizard.next();
        window.scroll(0, 0);
      }))
      .subscribe(data => {
          this.solicitudArrendamiento = data;
          this.idSolicitud = data['id']; // El idSolicitud se está enviado por medio de un @input.

          servicioAPIGuardar(); //Este método no esta aquí, pero es donde quiero que se ejecute.

        }, error => {
          log.debug(`Solicitud error: ${error.message}`);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Agrega la información del componente padre o hijo donde quieres ejecutar el método, ademas agrega como estas llamando a los componentes dentro de los otros componentes los selectores y variables de acceso

Comment: La idea es que suceda en el método `guardarSolicitud()`  o más concretamente al final del subscribe, ya que allí es donde obtengo como resultado el id de la solicitud, este lo envío a través de un `@input`, lo que no sé es como ejecuto el método del hijo `servicioAPIGuardar()`

Comment: Por eso te digo que subas el codigo , ya que con eso es mas facil ayudarte, edita tu pregunta

Comment: Pregunta actualizada

Comment: Ese codigo que agregas, es de cual componente ? te digo que subas los componentes por que necesito saber como estas llamando cada componente para su comunicacion , supongo que debes de tener algo como esto `@ViewChild('infoJuridicoComponent', { static: false }) infoJuridicoComponent: InfoJuridicosComponent;` o no se como estas comunicando, no se como tienes declarado la variables dices en un `@input` pero no se que tipo de dato, lo que yo hago para acceder a metodos de otros componentes es llamar la variable `InfoJuridicosComponent` y ya accedes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias maneras de resolver este problema pero te ejemplifico las dos mas comunes:

- Servicio compartido

**Servicio**

```
export class ServiceExample {

    $emitter = new EventEmitter();

    emitirEvento() {
        this.$emitter.emit();
    }   

}
```

**Componente padre**

```
export class PadreComponent {

 constructor(service: ServiceExample) {}

 guardarSolicitud() {
     // Tu código...
     this.service.emitirEvento();
 }

}
```

**Componente hijo**

```
export class PadreComponent {

 constructor(service: ServiceExample) {
   service.$emitter.subscribe(() => {
     this.servicioAPIGuardar()
   });
 }

 servicioAPIGuardar() {
   // Tu código
 }

}
```

---

- Con referencia de elemento

**Componente padre**

```
export class ComponentePadre {

    @ViewChild(ComponenteHijo) hijo: ComponenteHijo;

    guardarSolicitud() {
         // Tu código...
         this.hijo.servicioAPIGuardar();
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba, lo implemente con el objeto emitter y funciona perfecto.