# ¿Como paso información de un componente a otro sin que tengan relación?

Tags: angular

Necesito saber como pasar información entre dos componentes de una aplicación de Angular pero no tienen ninguna relación entre ellos. No tengo un parent que una a los dos.

Necesito pasar la variable cabecera del componente 1 al 2

Primer Componente

```
  export class Componente 1 implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}
     contador: number;
     cabecera: Cabecera;

    ngOnInit() {
      this.appService.getOf(this.inputOf).subscribe(data => {
            if (data.erpDataObjects.length !== 0) {
              console.log(data);
              this.cabecera.maquina = data.erpDataObjects[0].head.maq;
              this.cabecera.nomMaquina = data.erpDataObjects[0].head.nameMaq;
              this.cabecera.articulo = data.erpDataObjects[0].head.arti;
              this.cabecera.nomArticulo = data.erpDataObjects[0].head.nameArti;
              this.cabecera.of = this.inputOf;
            }
          }

    }
```

componente 2

```
export class Componente2 implements OnInit {

      constructor() {}

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

En los html

Comment: Hola, puedes agregar el codigo que has intentado o lo que has investigado? Un saludo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo a través de un *servicio compartido* con **observables**. El primer componente, donde está declarada la *variable cabecera*, se encargaria de **emitir** el evento del servicio, y el segundo componente, que es el que *recibe*, se **suscribe** a ese evento del servicio para obtener el valor una vez emitido.

Te dejo una pregunta que ya contesté para que veas el ejemplo de cómo se aplica el servicio compartido.

[Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326092/ejecutar-m%C3%A9todo-del-componente-hijo-desde-el-componente-padre-angular/326939?noredirect=1#comment593167_326939)