# Traer vista y Ejecutar método del componente Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular7

Tengo un Componente lista que me llama un componente detalle que sirve para Mostrar los datos que están en la lista y poder modificarlos o actualizarlos.

Para esto utilice ViewChild de referencia de elemento (ver este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/326939/24490)) así como para Mostrar el Detalle y ocultar la lista; el Detalle debe mostrarme el form de los datos en cada input y poder modificarlo.

el componente lista (vale Aclarar que estoy utilizando este código como ejemplo) lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
export class usersListComponent implements OnInit {


@ViewChild(usersDetailsComponent)
 private editusers: usersDetailsComponent;
 usuario = []

showDetails: boolean;
mostrarForm: boolean;

constructor(private _http : HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
   .subscribe((datos: any[]) => this.usuario = datos)
}
 EditarUser(usuario: any){
   this.showDetails = !this.showDetails
   this.mostrarForm = this.showDetails;
   this.editusers.getUserEdit(usuario);
 }
}
```

tengo el metodo EditarUser que me muestra o no las vistas, y me llama el metodo del viewChild getUserEdit(param)

en el html:

```html
 <table class="table table-hover" *ngIf="!mostrarForm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>user name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>WebSite</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
      <tr *ngFor="let user of usuario">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        <td>{{user.website}}</td>
        <td>
        <button id="btnEditar" (click)="EditarUser(user)">Edit</button>
        </td>
        <td>
        <button id="btnBorrar">Borrar</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

   <app-users-details *ngIf="showDetails"></app-users-details>
```

En el componente Editar se tiene la siguiente forma...

```
export class usersDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  lstUser: any ={
  firstName: '',
  userName: '',
  email:'',
  webSite:''
};

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 getUserEdit(usr){
   this.lstUser.firstName = usr.name
   this.lstUser.userName =  usr.username
   this.lstUser.email = usr.email
  this.lstUser.webSite =usr.website
  }
  }
```

El ejemplo completo lo tengo en [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ejecutar-metodo-vwchild-con-referencia-de-elemento?file=src/app/users-details/users-details.component.ts), vale recordar nuevamente que los datos y los componentes son para muestra.

En el ejemplo me indica el siguiente error: **ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'getUserEdit' of undefined** y no trae los datos de la lista a los detalles.

en mi proyecto, no TRAE los datos de la lista a los detalles... esta mostrando el formulario detalle pero no los datos! Que error o que me esta faltando para que funcione, y me lleve los datos de la lista al detalle?

Comment: El error es que `editusers`es undefined, por lo que no puedes llamar a ningún método sobre ese valor.

Comment: hola @PabloLozano no entiendo editusers?? yo tengo es **getUserEdit** y es un metodo, sobre cual valor te refieres?

Comment: TIenes esta línea: `this.editusers.getUserEdit(usuario);`. Si `this.editusers` es undefined, se produce ese error.

Comment: ah entiendo!! ese editusers es la variable del viewChild

 @ViewChild(usersDetailsComponent)
  private editusers: usersDetailsComponent;

Comment: @PabloLozano si tengo definida la variable editusers como un viewChild porque dice que esta undefined??

Comment: `editusers` será `undefined` porque el componente siempre estará oculto (`*ngIf="showDetails"`) y por lo tanto no se va renderizar en el dom.

Comment: @hawks si ya quite el ngIf ...y funciona en stackblitz... mirare en mi proyecto

Comment: @ger, hola hace unos días te respondí a la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/436479/c%c3%b3mo-agregar-una-lista-a-una-consulta-linq?noredirect=1#comment779571_436479, por favor revisa la respuesta que di ahí y de ser correcta te agradecería volvieras a abrir esa publicación, disculpa que te haya escrito por aquí, no sabia por donde más hacerlo, gracias

Comment: @Japv perdona la había planteado mal, por eso la elimine, como tu sugeriste no era lo que buscaba. igual la resolví

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes pasarle el usuario a editar por `@Input` al `app-user-details`.

```javascript
// Intenta poner el nombre de la clase en mayuscula(best practice)
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit {

  usuarios = []
  selectedUser: any;

  showDetails: boolean;
  mostrarForm: boolean;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .subscribe((datos: any[]) => this.usuarios = datos)
  }
  EditarUser(usuario: any) {
    this.showDetails = !this.showDetails
    this.mostrarForm = this.showDetails;
    this.selectedUser = usuario; 
  }
}


export class UsersDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  @Input() usuario: any = {
    firstName: '',
    userName: '',
    email: '',
    webSite: ''
  };

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

```html
<app-users-details *ngIf="showDetails" [usuario]="selectedUser"></app-users-details>
```

[Input](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Comment: no pasa información hice tu modificacion en stack blitz                               pero no  funciona, los input estan vacios... he omitido algo? este es el link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ejecutar-metodo-vwchild-con-referencia-de-elemento?file=src/app/users-details/users-details.component.ts

Comment: tenias en app-users-details [usuario]="usuario"  lo cambie a **selectedUser ** Gracias!! y si lo de nombrar la clase en mayúscula si lo hago solo que para hacerlo rápido!! es un ejemplo.